# Could not access <welcome-file> with Spring

Tags: spring

When I run SpringWebApplication (localhost:8008/SpringWebApplication/), I am expecting welcome-file to be rendered.

But it is throwing 404

Could somebody tell me if I am missing any configuration. Do I need a Controller certainly to access welcome-file? OR Can welcome-file be accessible without a Controller.

Here are the files in my application SpringWebApplication.

---

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringWebApplication</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springWeb</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>springWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

   <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springWeb-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>

    <listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>
Index Page
</body>
</html>
```

---

springWeb-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

---

Console

```
May 21, 2014 7:15:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8008"]
May 21, 2014 7:15:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 21, 2014 7:15:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3803 ms
May 21, 2014 7:15:50 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringWebApplication/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springWeb'
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` instead of `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` in the `servlet-mapping` for the DispatcherServlet.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add something like this in your config file:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" 
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```